# How to keep Flutter build output from bringing back old debug output?

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

Since upgrading to the New Flutter 1.12.13 release I have a strange effect in both VSCode and Android Studio on Windows 10.
I'm describing here for VSCode which has a Debug Console.

Whenever I make a code change and hit F5 to recompile and redeploy my app the following happens:

The Debug Console clears as expected.

Then it outputs as expected:

`Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...`

Then it brings back all the debug output from all sessions I ran since the upgrade.
There are dozens of lines that look like this:

`I/flutter (14674): ----- performing reset -----
I/flutter (14674): starting wifiExec
I/flutter (14674): finished wifiExec
I/flutter (14674): starting seenExec
I/flutter (14674): SMS Status File loaded 1 entries.
I/flutter (14674): finished seenExec`

The texts to the right of the colons are my print statements.
The number in the parenthesis (14674) seems to be an identifier for the debug sessions and keeps increasing.

Lastly it outputs as expected:

`√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.`

I can't seem to find a file where those logs are being kept. Getting all those extra lines in the build output makes it really hard to find the actual build errors.

How can I stop the build from bringing back the old debug output?

**UPDATE:**

I observed this a little more, and it seems that the old debug output is from BEFORE the upgrade. The output is from 15 sessions and is the same with every build.

Is it possible that this is somewhere stored in the saved emulator image? I just don't understand how this would be inserted into the build output...

**UPDATE 2:**

It turns out this is in fact stored on the emulator image. I was able to get rid of the old debug output during build by choosing `Wipe Data` in the AVD.

However, after deploying the app, running it in the debugger, stopping it in the debugger, I get the output from that debug session in the next build/deploy. This did not happen before the upgrade to 1.12.

I had also updated the emulator to the latest version, but don't remember what version it was before this problem started happening.

Comment: This a known issue. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46815 (there's comments about workaround if you using Android Studio). As of flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.5, this has not been fixed yet in VS Code.